# Installing Google Maps/Places API Cocoa pod on iOS. How?

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoa, installation

I'm trying to install the Google Maps API onto my Macbook Pro. I have followed the instructions on the website [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/start) but got as far as Step 3. How do I 
1) go about creating a Podfile for the Google Maps API, and
2) and use it to install the API and its dependencies?

I have looked at the Cocoa Pods guides but its unclear to me (with zero coding experience) as to what exactly should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a pretty high level question that could be answered w/ the cocoapods documentation, but I will give you a high-level overview of what you need to do so that when you read the documentation you have an idea of what's going on

1) You need to install cocoapods (`sudo gem install cocoapods`)
2) You need to create a podfile for your project.  A podfile has 2 main pieces, one being that it will identify the sources where the cocoapods you want exist (git repositories), and it will also contain the list of the cocoapods that you want as well as options such as specific versions, branches, etc.
3) You then will navigate to your project directory and run a `pod install`.
4) This will search for the `podfile`, which will identify which pods it needs.
5) For that, it will look at the repositories (sources) for `.podspec` files, which then tell it where to grab the files for a certain pod.
6) Cocoapods will then download the files specified in the `.podspec`, for the pod that was specified in the `podfile`
7) After that it will generate a new "Pods" `.xcproj` in your `.xcworkspace` where you can then link your files from the pod